# How to check if all elements in a node list have the same class or the same style property value?

Tags: javascript

I created memory game. The only problem is that when the game is done and the player wins, it doesn't console.log('win)
Code:

```
 let checkingImages = document.querySelectorAll('.card')
 checkingImages = Array.from(checkingImages)
 let check = checkingImages.every((each)=>{
     each.classList.contains('matched')
 })
 if(check == true){
     console.log('win')
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `every` method, you're only checking for the class's existence, not actually returning anything.

You have to write it like this:

```
let checkingImages = document.querySelectorAll('.card')
checkingImages = Array.from(checkingImages)
let check = checkingImages.every(item => item.classList.contains('matched'))

console.log(check)
```

Or like this, if you want to stick to your original answer:

```
let checkingImages = document.querySelectorAll('.card')
checkingImages = Array.from(checkingImages)
let check = checkingImages.every((item) => {
    return item.classList.contains('matched')
})

console.log(check)
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot! Your answer was perfect! It definitely works!